# Insert a plugin manually into wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working in worpress front page.

I want to add a plugin to the page at a specific location manually but adding the code to the page myself.

I basically want to include a plugin in a certain page on a certain location. So I'm create a div...

```
<div id="plugin-holder">
     **Plugin-will-appear-here-with-this-code**
</div>
```

Don't anyone know how this is done please?

Thanks

Comment: Could you specify how the plugin components you want to add to your frontpage are usually added and what plugin(s) you're talking about? If you are more specific about your problem, I'm sure we can adequately help. With the above info all answers are just a shot in the dark.

Comment: This question makes no sense, and my attempts to get clarification aren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the relevant plugin code to `functions.php`.

I suspect you'll want to use some [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), like `is_home()` to pinpoint your location. But maybe not, depending on what you are trying to do,

Also, if you're trying to to insert from a pre-existing plug-in, make sure you remove the `register_activation_hook` or `activate_pluginname` action.

Comment: Suppose there is already a plugin called: plugin1 .... I want to create a <div></div> and insert the code the will make that plugin appear in the Div ... know what I mean?

Comment: @Satch3000: Not really :) What does the plugin do? It makes something display? Can you just tell us what the plugin is maybe?

Comment: What I mean is that if I create a html <div> </div> and between them I want a particular plugin to appear ... how would I code that?

Comment: @Satch3000: plugins don't generally "appear" anywhere. They filter native wordpress functions to perform some additional task. Not sure what you mean. Again, please tell us what the plugin is, or what it displays. What exactly do you want between those `<div>` tags?

Comment: include a plugin in between ... see main question for update. thanks

Comment: quite obvious what he wants to happen, script a plugin into a wordpress page/post via a short code. Your answer advises him to register activation hooks, which is a code solution, not markup and totally over complicates things. Brian C below has the nicest solution.

Answer (score 9):

If you're wanting a plugin to appear somewhere, you'll be looking for "shortcode" functionality.

This is actually surprisingly easy to code, check out the examples in the Codex under [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) - ie:

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    // ... do more things here ...
return "text to replace shortcode";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

Once you've called these functions you can use [bartag] in code and it will run your function and replace the shortcode with the generated text your function returns.

If you're adding shortcode functionality to your site, it generally makes most sense to code a really simple plugin and put it in that.  The reason why this works best is that, over time, it's really easy to forget and upgrade a theme by mistake (or even change to a new theme) and thus break your site by losing your custom code in your former functions.php.  Surprisingly, this is pretty easy to achieve and only requires some specially formatted comments at the top of your plugin file and a little common sense in coding - there are many tutorials and "how to"s around!

Here's a useful shortcode tutorial: http://www.reallyeffective.co.uk/archives/2009/06/22/how-to-code-your-own-wordpress-shortcode-plugin-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin supports a sidebar widget you can simply "widgitize" the div tag that you wish to insert the plugin into.. Google the term and you are gonna find many resources.